# How use AsyncStorage with React Native and hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using the `react-native-community/react-native-async-storage` lib.
For instance, I tried to make something similar to React Web but it did not work

```
 const [list, setList] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(setList));
 }, [list]);
```

Comment: You've used `JSON.stringify` on the `setList` function. I imagine you meant to stringify the list, i.e. `JSON.stringify(list)`

Comment: Basic examples and concept of hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

export default function App(props) {

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list)); <-- Not use "setList", use "list" here -->
  }, [list]);

}
```

> setList is method which use to set/update list data

Answer (score -2):

In react native, AsyncStorage is async in nature.

u need to add async/await in the function.

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);


useEffect(async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(setList));
 }, [list]);
```

Comment: this is poor code, while it does work, declaring async on a useEffect can cause memory leaks so just be aware of that. To avoid that just put this inside the useEffect and then put whatever you're awaiting inside of it 

(async () => {
 
})();